# Select Statement in SQL like self join

Tags: sql, select

I have a Table 
TABLE EMP (
    EMPNO     NUMBER(4),
  ENAME     VARCHAR2(10),
  JOB       VARCHAR2(9),
  MGR       NUMBER(4),
  HIREDATE  DATE,
  SAL       NUMBER(7,2),
  COMM      NUMBER(7,2),
  DEPTNO    NUMBER(2));

Here is the question 
You need a report that lists the employee name, their manager name, and the department name in which they work. The MGR column stores the EMPNO not the name. Write the SELECT statement.

How would I write this SELECT STATEMENT?

SELECT ENAME, MGR, DEPTNO, .....
FROM EMP

Comment: VLOOKUPs require a specific field to lookup, what would that be in this instance, the EMPNO?

Comment: The MGR column hold the employee number of the manager, I want it to look at that number, then find the ENAME that is associated with it and make a column with the ENAME and name it MGR_NAME.

Comment: You need to use a self join. See this [blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/08/sql-server-the-self-join-inner-join-and-outer-join) for an example.

Comment: SELECT EMPNO,ENAME, MGR, (??????)
FROM EMP 
JOIN EMP ON EMPNO =MGR;  ......How would I get it to be another column?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get the employee's manager.

```
SELECT A.ENAME AS EMPLOYEE, B.ENAME AS MANAGER, A.DEPTNO AS DEPTNO
FROM EMP A, EMP B
WHERE A.MGR = B.EMPNO;
```

**Illustration:**

*EMP-1's manager is MGR-1, EMP-2's manager is MGR-2, MGR-1 and MGR-2 are their own managers*

```
SELECT * from EMP;
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB    MGR  HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
1       EMP-1   ADMIN   5   01-01-2000  2000.05 1000.05 10
2       EMP-2   ADMIN   4   01-02-2000  3000.05 3000.05 11
5       MGR-1   ADMIN   5   01-01-1995  9000.05 9000.05 9
4       MGR-2   ADMIN   4   01-05-1995  8000.05 8000.05 9

-- query output
EMPLOYEE    MANAGER DEPTNO
MGR-1       MGR-1   9
EMP-1       MGR-1   10
MGR-2       MGR-2   9
EMP-2       MGR-2   11
```